# NodeJS user authorization get specific data

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am working on a web app, where every user should see his own categories. So if i log in as user1, it should show user1's own categories and if i log in as user2 it should show only user2's categories.

Right now, no matter which user i log in, it does show all categories.
I am using expressjs and mongoose.

right now this is how i get my categories:

### app.js

```
app.get("/category", function(req, res) {
  Category.find(function(err, foundCategories) {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect("/panel-admin");
    } else {
      res.render("category", { Categories: foundCategories });
    }
  });
});
```

### categories.js

```
// MONGOOSE/MODEL CONFIG
 var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     title: String,
     image: String,
     shop: {
         id: {
             type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
             ref: "User"
         },
         username: String
     }

 });
```

### user.js

```
// MONGOOSE/MODEL CONFIG
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
```

Comment: So how would we know which categories belong to which user? What you need to understand when asking questions of others is that you need to give them as much information to go on as you have yourself. Without that, people don't really understand what you are asking or how to solve it. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You dont need to know what which category belongs to which user. I am asking if i am logged in as user1, it should only get categories that belong to the user1.

Comment: We cant see your database. So we don't know what field has the user information in it, if any. You need to include that in your question in some form that we can see what needs to be done.

Comment: Okay thanks, i added some code, is this okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure Saeed's approach will work, as we're just loading `/categories` rather than `/categories/:id`, so there won't be any information in `req.params.id`.

I have something very similar in my app that uses `req.user._id` which can then be used to find all categories with a `shop.id` that equals that user.

I've amended my code slightly to use your references:

```
router.get("/category", middlewareObj.isLoggedIn, function(req,res) {
    Category.find({"shop.id": req.user._id},function(err,allCats){       //Only find categories linked to current user
        if (err) {
          res.redirect("/panel-admin");
        } else {
          res.render("category", { Categories: allCats });
        }                 
    });
});
```

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `findOne` function and pass it a variable which specified each user. for example I passed it `id` that achieved from `req` object.

```
app.get("/category", function(req, res) {
  // var id = get id or other specific key from req
  Category.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, foundCategories) {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect("/panel-admin");
    } else {
      res.render("category", { Categories: foundCategories });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks.
the way the app is built, is that when i click on categories link, it should show all categories that belongs to the user. so i tried your suggestion with Category.find({_id: req.params.id}).....

but it doesnt show any categories

Comment: I said `findOne` @cmt123

Comment: Does your documents in Mongo has property `_id`? exactly with this name? or you stored it as another name? It seems query run well with no error, but there is no document with that params. @cmt123

Comment: when i check mlab database, there is a property called _id,

also i did assign the _id: req.params.id

Comment: And that's mapped to `id` of each user?? Is `req.params.id` have right value? There is no error with function or usage. Your data and values have a problem somewhere. Can you insert an example of user info in db and also `req.params.id`? @cmt123

Comment: every user is assigned an _id, and everytime i create a category it will get ref to the user id who created that category